# Telerik ASP.NET AJAX RadTreeView Display Hierarchical Data from two Joined Tables

Tags: asp.net, telerik, webforms

I want to use Telerik RAD TreeView control to display Departments and Employees in them like the following:

```
-Dep1
   --Emp1
   --Emp2
-Dep2
   --Emp3
-Dep3
  --Emp4
  --Emp5
```

I have 2 table Employees and Department with one-to-many relationship, so DepartmentId is in both Tables.

All online demos is about to display hierarchical data using self reference table, so How to implement this from 2 joined tables?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make your data query statement look like the hierarchical data you want to present.

Trying querying your data with a statement like:

```
SELECT 
    DeptId as Id,   
    NULL as ParentId,   
    Name 
FROM 
    dept
UNION
SELECT 
    EmpID*1000 as Id,           
    DeptId as ParentId,         
    Name
FROM 
    Emp
```

Then you can bind your RadTreeView with arguments like the following:

```
<telerik:RadTreeView ID="RadTreeView1" runat="server" Width="100%" Height="250px"
                DataSourceID="MyDataSource" DataFieldID="Id" DataFieldParentID="ParentId"
                DataTextField="Name">
</telerik:RadTreeView>
```

Comment: It not work if you set Parent Id for Department = 0, I set its value to NULL and it's working.